# Perl Errors when running

Tags: perl

I have been working endlessly on perl program that manages a user and password list. It has contains the specific functions of , adding a user, modifying a user, generating a user list, and deleting a user.

However, I am running into several errors, I am hoping you guys might be able to help me fix.

Here are the errors

```
C:\Users\mte>perl C:\Users\mte\Desktop\org11.pl
 Useless use of lc in void context at C:\Users\mte\Desktop/org22.pm line 25.
 Useless use of private variable in void context at          
 C:\Users\mte\Desktop\org11.pl
 line 16.
 Useless use of private variable in void context at     
 C:\Users\mte\Desktop\org11.pl
 line 18.
 Useless use of a variable in void context at C:\Users\mte\Desktop\org11.pl    
 line
 72.
 Name "main::userNameStorage" used only once: possible typo at    
 C:\Users\mte\Desktop\org11.pl line 72.
 Name "main::nameofile" used only once: possible typo at    
 C:\Users\mte\Desktop\org11.pl line 23.
 what is the name of the filename:
 matthew
 Use of uninitialized value $nameofile in scalar chomp at    
 C:\Users\mte\Desktop\org11.pl line 23, <> line 1.
 Unsuccessful stat on filename containing newline at    
 C:\Users\mte\Desktop\org11.pl line 25, <> line 1.
 readline() on closed filehandle $filehandle at   
 C:\Users\mte\Desktop\org11.pl >line 38.

 User Accounts
 -------------
 i = Insert new user account
 m = modify existing user account
 r = Remove existing user account
 g = Generate list of accounts
 q = Quit

 Enter Choice:i
 Undefined subroutine &main::insertUser called at   
 C:\Users\mte\Desktop\org11.pl line 85, <> line 2.
```

Source Code for ***org22.pl***:

```
#!/bin/perl
use lib "C:\\Users\\mte\\Desktop";

use org22;
#use strict;
use warnings;

$filename;
$filehandle;
$nameoffile;

%useroptionsfunction = (
    'i' => \&insertUser,
    'm' => \&modifyUser,
    'r' => \&removeUser,
    'g' => \&generateList
);

$nameoffile; # name of file

$filename; # the full path of the file

print "what is the name of the filename:", "\n";
$nameoffile = <>;
chomp( $nameofile );

if ( -e $nameoffile ) {
    open( $filehandle, "<", $nameoffile );
}
else {
    open( $filehandle, ">", $nameoffile );
}

# load user accoutns from filefield;
%useraccountshash = ();

while ( $loadlines = <$filehandle> )    # load all data into hash if the file already exists

{

    # this array temporarily holds the user data while we prepare it to go to hash

    @myarray = split( /:/, $loadlines );    # split the line at the colon, will put username into index 0 in the array, and password in index 1

    $username = $myarray[0];

    $password = $myarray[1];
    chomp( $password );

    $username =~ s/[^a-zA-Z0-9]//g;
    $username = lc( $username );

    $password =~ s/\'//g;

    # now we are putting in the user name and password into the hash , array to va, variiables, variables to hash

    $useraccounthash{$username} = $password;

}

#user account interface
print "\t", "\n", "User Accounts", "\n";
print "-------------", "\n";

print "i = Insert new user account",      "\n";
print "m = modify existing user account", "\n";
print "r = Remove existing user account", "\n";
print "g = Generate list of accounts",    "\n";
print "q = Quit",                         "\n", "\n";

$userNameStorage;

#insert new user account interface

print( "Enter Choice:" );
$input = <>;
chomp( $input );

if ( $input ne 'q' ) {

    if ( $input eq "i" ) {
        $command          = $useroptionsfunction{$input};
        %useraccountshash = $command->( \%useraccountshash );

    }

    #modify username and password interface
    elsif ( $input eq "m" ) {
        $command          = $useroptionsfunction{m};
        %useraccountshash = $command->( \%useraccountshash );

    }

    #remove the user interface
    elsif ( $input eq "r" ) {
        $command          = $useroptionsfunction{r};
        %useraccountshash = $command->( \%useraccountshash );

    }

    #generate list of accounts
    elsif ( $input eq "g" ) {
        $command          = $useroptionsfunction{g};
        %useraccountshash = $command->( \%useraccountshash );

    }

}

if ( $input eq "q" ) {

    print "Quitting Program...";

}

close( $filehandle );
print "save changes? type, y or n";

$userinput = <>;
chomp( $userinput );

if ( $userinput eq 'y' ) {
    open( $filehandle, ">", $filename );

    for $usernames1 ( keys %useraccounthash )

    {    # used to iterate through the hash and pull out usernames
        print $filehandle "$usernames1:$useraccountshash{$usernames1}\n";    #goes through keys and writes the key and value to file
    }

    close( $filehandle );
}

1;
```

source code for ***org22.pm***

```
package org;
use strict;
use Exporter;
use warnings;

my $userNameStorage;
my $insertUserName;
my $newpassword;
my %temporaryhash;
my $userName;

use vars qw(@ISA @EXPORT);
@ISA = qw(Exporter);
@EXPORT = ( "insertUser", "modifyUser", "removeUser", "generateList" );

sub insertUser {

    my $grabparameter = shift;
    my %temporaryhash = %$grabparameter;

    print "Enter Username:";
    my $insertUserName = <>;
    chomp( $insertUserName );

    lc( $insertUserName );
    $insertUserName =~ s/[^a-zA-Z0-9]//g;

    if ( exists( $temporaryhash{$insertUserName} ) ) {

        print "user already exists";
        return %temporaryhash;

        # referenceing whoel hash use percent, when refereing part of the
        # hash use $
    }

    $userNameStorage = $insertUserName;

    #$userNameStorage = ($input);

    print "Enter Password:";
    my $insertUserPassword = <>;
    chomp( $insertUserPassword );

    $userNameStorage = ( $insertUserPassword );
    chomp( $insertUserPassword );

    $insertUserPassword =~ s/\'//g;
    $temporaryhash{$insertUserName} = $insertUserPassword;

    # if the user name doesnt exist, get a password for it, then load key
    # into hash, where key is the user name and the value is the password

    return %temporaryhash;

}

sub modifyUser {

    my $grabparameter = shift;
    my %temporaryhash = %$grabparameter;

    print "Username to modify:";
    my $modifyUsername = <>;
    chomp( $modifyUsername );

    my $modifyUserName =~ s/[^a-zA-Z0-9]//g;
    if ( exists( $temporaryhash{$modifyUsername} ) )

      # checking if username exists, and if it does, then prompt for
      # password

    {

        print "password:, " . "\n";
        my $oldpassword = <>;
        chomp( $oldpassword );

        if ( $oldpassword eq $temporaryhash{$modifyUserName} )

        {
            print "new password: ";

            $newpassword = <>;
            chomp( $newpassword );
            $newpassword =~ s/\'//g;

            return %temporaryhash;

        }

        print "Invalid password";
        return %temporaryhash;

    }

    print "user does not exist";

    return %temporaryhash;

}

sub removeUser {

    my $grabparameter = shift;
    my %temporaryhash = %$grabparameter;

    print "User to remove:";
    my $removeuser = <>;
    chomp( $removeuser );

    if ( exists( $temporaryhash{$removeuser} ) ) {
        delete( $temporaryhash{$removeuser} );
        return %temporaryhash;
    }
    print "user does not exist";

    return %temporaryhash;

}

sub generateList {

    my $grabparameter = shift;
    my %temporaryhash = %$grabparameter;

    for my $userName ( keys %temporaryhash ) {

        print "----------------------------", "\n";
        print "List of User Accounts",        "\n";
        print "\n";
        print "$userName: $temporaryhash{$userName}";

        print $userName. ":" . $temporaryhash{$userName} . "\n";

        #print user name and passowrd, then colon, then it will print the associated
        value with the username

    }

    return %temporaryhash;
}

1;
```

Comment: Giving errors is good, but show us your code, this will be better for anyone

Comment: i added my quote beneath the errors? @GillesQuenot

Comment: Yes, now it's OK since your editing

Comment: Don't comment 'use strict'

Comment: Is this homework? It's terrible code. It's laid out very badly so that it's impossible to see the structure (I've reformatted it so that I could read it a little better) and you've written *far* too much before starting to test it. You should write just two or three lines of code at a time, then test that and add some more code only when it works properly. Disabling `use strict` is a *very bad* move. It would have saved you from many misspellings such as `useraccountshash` / `useraccounthash`. There's there's really far too much wrong with it to be able tl help you. Try again with this advice

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your script does not have a sub named `insertUser` because `use org22;` imports from the package `org22`, which doesn't exist, much less exports anything. You want to import from package `org`. Solve this by giving the file and the package the same name.

```
use org22;
org22.pm
package org22;
```

or

```
use org;
org.pm
package org;
```

Actually, since all-lowercase module names are reserved for pragmas, why don't you rename it to something more conventional.

```
use Org22;
Org22.pm
package Org22;
```

or

```
use Org;
Org.pm
package Org;
```

The warnings indicate a number of other problems, but I only have time to address the main one. Start by adding `use strict;` and fixing the errors it finds. Then, address the warnings. Adding `use diagnostics;` will try to explain the warnings to you.

Comment: It should also be called `Org22`

Comment: Yeah, all-lowercase module names are reserved for pragmas.